# pass param in middleware expressjs/nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in nodeJS project where I wanted to pass param in middleware so that I can validate in the code.

E.g Middleware I created is as below

```
'use strict';
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import BadRequest from '../../../errors/BadRequest';
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import ResponseFormatter from '../../../util/ResponseFormatter';

export default function middlewareWithParam (options) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        // Implement the middleware function based on the options object
        
        return next();
        //ResponseFormatter.error(new BadRequest('03'), req, res);
    };
}
```

Now I want use this middleware in the controller class so that by passing different values per end-point middle can validate the request.

E.g.

```
Controller class

import { middlewareWithParam } from '../middlewares/validators/Role/middlewareWithParam';

export default class RoleController extends BaseController {
    paths = [
        {
            'method': 'GET', 'path': '/', 'middlewares': [middlewareWithParam({option1 : '1',option2 : '2'})], 'handler': this.getRoleList
        },
        {
            'method': 'GET', 'path': '/getRoleByID', 'middlewares': [middlewareWithParam({option1 : '3',option2 : '4'})], 'handler': this.getRoleByID
        }
}
```

but I am getting error that

```
'middlewares': [(0, _middlewareWithParam.middlewareWithParam)()],
                                                                   ^

TypeError: (0 , _middlewareWithParam.middlewareWithParam) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for destructuring. remove the curley braces. change

```
import { middlewareWithParam } from '../middlewares/validators/Role/middlewareWithParam';
```

to

```
import  middlewareWithParam from '../middlewares/validators
```

Have a look at https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html

Edit:

Or do something like this to define it.

```
function middlewareWithParam(options) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
            // return next();
    };
}

module.exports = {
    middlewareWithParam
}
```

Or remove the default.

```
export function middlewareWithParam(options) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
            // return next();
    };
}
```